# How to ignore specific file for specific python version

Tags: python

Some of files in my application are for python 3 only.

can I ignore these file if code runs on python 2?

Example:

```
import sys
if sys.version_info.major < 3:
    return  # this doesn't work

<other code should to be ignored for python < 3>
```

I know I can do this way:

```
import sys
if sys.version_info.major < 3:
    pass
else:
    <other code should to be ignored for python < 3>
```

But the question is, can I avoid include entire file context inside `else` scope?

The alternative question, can I just exclude this file from `__init__.py`?

Comment: Maybe its better to make the import statement in the importing file conditional on the python version. You could simply add an assertion in those files to ensure they are not accidentally imported by the wrong python version.

Comment: What do you mean "files in my module"? Do you mean "modules in my package"?

Comment: Edited question, it is not package. Just regular app. And thank you for negative votes.

Answer (score 0):

For the moment I only found this solution: https://github.com/evanplaice/pypreprocessor/blob/master/Examples/py2and3.py

It requires to use **pypreprocessor** package and it simulates C style preprocessor directives. So my code would be this way:

```
import sys
from pypreprocessor import pypreprocessor

#exclude
if sys.version_info.major < 3:
    pypreprocessor.defines.append('python3')

pypreprocessor.parse()
#endexclude

#ifdef python3
# <other code should to be ignored for python < 3>
#endif
```

Please post other solutions if you have any